# Linux 16.04 - can't install Install Android Studio?

Tags: apt, 16.04, package-management, android

I am following the official [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html):

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zlib.i686
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'zlib.i686'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'zlib.i686'
E: Unable to locate package ncurses-libs.i686
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ncurses-libs.i686'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ncurses-libs.i686'
E: Unable to locate package bzip2-libs.i686
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'bzip2-libs.i686'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'bzip2-libs.i686'
```

And even with:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Result:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

Any ideas why? How I can get around to this?

Comment: Yo are **not** following the guide for Ubuntu, you're following the guide for Fedora, quite different packages to install.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 lib32stdc++6
```

It worked for me.
If you don't have multi-arch support enabled, you'll need to run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```